# SerialPort not recognizing my combobox text - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, com-port

My `SerialPort` class is not recognizing my combobox info. I have this piece of code below, where it is reading all the COM Ports available on my PC:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
{
    var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>()
                              .ToList()
                              .Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());

    var portList = portnames.Select(n => n);

    foreach (string s in portList)
    {
        cb1.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

The COM Ports available are being added to my combobox, not sure if I have to add something here, because when I run my code, I can see the COM Ports available in my combobox `cb1`.

Then the value selected on the combo box should be passed as a parameter for my COM Port reads the data that is coming through:

```
try
{
    port = new SerialPort(cb1.Text, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

    port.Open();

    void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        noteData = sp.ReadExisting().ToString();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));

        void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dtBoxNote.Text += noteData;
        }
    }

    Log.Information("This port has been initialized.");
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    Log.Fatal(error.ToString());
}
```

Here is my problem, when I select the value in the ComboxBox the data is not coming through, however, if I delete `cb1.Text` and hard code the any COM Port number, for example `"COM11"`, I can see the data coming through, when I run my program I am also receiving a warn that my COM Port is empty, which it will be fulfilled after I select my COM Port.

How can I use my combo box info into as parameter for my `SerialPort` class? I have tried to use `.SelectedItem`, `Index` and a bunch of another options but none worked.

Thanks

Comment: Your question contains lots of unrelated details. It would be easier to read and understand if you would omit it: 1) You do not use really use the results of the ManagementObjectSearcher 2) It seems that your only problem ist that `cb1.Text` does not contains what you expect. All the rest of the SerialPort code is then irrelevant. Rather, please show us which strings you added to the combobox and what the value of `cb1.Text` is.

Comment: I forgot to mention the results of ```ManagementObjectSearcher```, its just below of  ```InitializeComponent();```, when I run my application and I click on ComboBox drop down list, it is already showing all my availables COM Ports. My final objective its to use the results of ```ManagementObjectSearcher```  so the user can select the desired COM Port and start to receive the data. I used ```cb1.Text``` because I thought that would read my COM Port choice. But it didn't work.

Comment: As mentioned by Klaus, you are mixing up things here, it seems. You do not _need_ the `ManagementObjectSearcher`, since `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` already gets you what you need. Instead of the `Text` property, preferably use the `SelectedIndex` property (and do a lookup). Also make sure, your combobox is set so random input is not possible.

Comment: I am using `ManagementObjectSearcher` like that because I need a description of each com port data I have available, indeed `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` gets the COM Ports but not in a way I needed. But thanks. What I really need here, and the reason I create this topic, is to use the value selected on my ComboxBox as parameter for my SerialPort class.

Comment: The SelectedIndexi is not working either. Pretty sure that is not something hard to fix/resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix my issue, passing my whole block of the port reader, inside the Combo Box.

```
         private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                port = new SerialPort(cb1.Text, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                port.Open();

                void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
                    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                    someData = sp.ReadExisting().ToString();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));

                    void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        dtBox.Text += someData;
                    }
                }

                Log.Information("Port has been initialized.");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Log.Fatal(error.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The error I was getting I believe its because my SerialPort settings it was been initialized before my combo box. Once I move the my code "inside" the combo box, my issue was gone, because now, probably, they are being initialized together.